# How to deploy my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Currently I have only been deploying my application on localhost, but I would like to get it onto my website. 
What are my options, and what would you recommend?

I know I can deploy it to my VPS, but if I have a domain at a webhotel hosting service(one.com), is there anyway I can deploy it threw that? I know I can use like Heroku to host the application and link it to my domain. But I don't want to run it through Heroku, cause I want to host it "myself".

Any suggestions?
Thanks on advance!

Comment: Take a look at Capistrano

Comment: look in here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks

Comment: Thats great, thank you!

Comment: I would deploy once or twice to Heroku to make sure your app works in production and that the Rails stack is setup correctly. After you confirm this, then make the move to something more roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @sjagr, seems to me like you need a deployment solution that will allow you to deploy to your own server.

Here is a Digital Ocean tutorial that helped me a lot when I was trying to deploy my first application to my VPS using Capistrano:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma